# Symfony debug:translation shows missing translations which are already defined in bundles

Tags: php, symfony, translation

While working with symfony translations, I have overwritten a template file from one bundle and used the translation messages in project. Translation messages are defined very well according to domain (inside `messages.en.xlf`) in bundle and works fine.

But when I run the command `php bin/console debug:translation en --only-missing`, I see those messages are reported missing. I have tried with other bundles too. It behaves the same for all. Whenever I use any translation message outside the bundle, It reports missing error for those translation messages.

I have also tried with `php bin/console debug:translation en --only-missing BundleName` which works fine without showing any missing errors.

1. Why is `php bin/console debug:translation en --only-missing` reporting these defined translation messages as **Missing**?
2. Is there any possible way by which all the defined translation messages can be tracked using `php bin/console debug:translation` without any missing errors?

Comment: Issue is resolved. Solution is explained in github issue [#47562](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/47562) :)